# Removing extra whitespaces between characters from a string using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, regex, removing-whitespace

After extensive research I'm still puzzled about removing extra white spaces from a string.
My string source is an editable div in Jquery. I pass it via AJAX POST to php script.

```
$('#button').on('click', function () {
var text = $('#Editable_DIV').text();
$.ajax({
        url: 'foo.php',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {characters: text
        },...............

     )}; 
 )};
```

My foo.php with '12345     6' string content

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/(&nbsp;)+|\s\K\s+/','', $_POST['characters']));
```

It removes only 2 out of 5 white spaces.

```
12345   6
```

But when I hard coded the string like

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/(&nbsp;)+|\s\K\s+/','', '12345     6'));
```

It outputs like expected

```
12345 6
```

With only 1 white space between '5' and '6' characters. I tried many Regex expressions combinations, **urldecode()**, none worked. What's wrong with $_POST['characters']?

**UPD.**
I include echo and var_dump the content of $_POST['characters'] before any manipulation and string output after manipulation.

```
**Before:**

12345     6

C:\xampp\htdocs\foo.php:string '12345     6' (length=15)

**After:**

12345    6

C:\xampp\htdocs\foo.php:string '12345    6' (length=14)
```

Comment: Can you post the content of echo $_POST['characters']) before you process it with preg_replace etc. It may give some clues.

Comment: Also, not sure about this, but may need urldecode() to be run on $_POST['characters']) before trying to play with it?

Comment: Use `urlencode` on the value, and then check what percent encoding values you get in the places in question - that’ll help you determine what byte values you are actually dealing with.

Comment: Why are you using reset operator `\K`?

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester Check my updated question. urldecode() doesn't change anything. $_POST['characters'] before processing is '12345     6'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.Solution found.**

As it was mentioned, the source of my string is an editable html DIV, which I use instead of normal HTML text area. That makes my string very different than hard coded or PHP-maden string.
So, my string contains some white spaces written in a form of machine language/ASCII code, which I still couldn't figure out. There is NO WAY you can see this encoded white spaces.

That's why REGEX doesn't match '\t nbsp; " ", %C2 %A0%' etc. 
**Urldecode** function doesn't work either, as it's not URL encoded thing.  Instead of guessing what is sitting in those white spaces, I just encode them to html using this:

```
$data = htmlentities($_POST['characters']);
```

Now my string outputs this:

```
12345&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 6
```

I still can't figure out why my first 4 white spaces were converted to **nbsp** but the 5th one appears as a normal " " white space. But at least it explains why REGEX removed only 1 white space.

Then I easily remove/strip **nbsp** and extra spaces.

```
$stripped = trim(preg_replace('/(&nbsp;)+|\s\K\s+/','', $data));
```

Now my output looks as expected:
12345 6

Let's decode those html entities (if you had any html tags in your string) back to their respective characters:

```
$finalString = html_entity_decode($stripped);
```

Now everything is just perfect.

**To summarize the problem:** it appears that different browsers and different OS can replace HTML white space with different things. I think it's not a bug, rather it's behavioral thing of browser/OS. Just let the machine to convert their encoding to an universal HTML entity and then use REGEX to match that entity and remove it.
I hope I saved lots of time for some people.

Answer (score 0):

I added one more function after it. Please check it.

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/(&nbsp;)+|\s\K\s+/','', $_POST['characters']));
$string = str_replace(' ','',$string);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it has same effect - it removes only 2 white spaces instead of 4. Looks like some html code is sitting in place of white spaces. I don't know what to think.

Comment: Hard coded value is working, while value passed through $_POST doesn't.

Comment: In that case, the input you are getting is not spaces. You need to check that.